# Hybrid PWA: what browser does it run in once installed to home screen?

Tags: android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app, progressive-web-apps

I'm new to mobile app development and progressive web apps, and I'm trying to understand something fairly fundamental about hybrid mobile apps.

Assume that I've built a PWA, that I'm using a framework (Ionic 3) which takes care of the app's "install to home screen" functionality (providing a manifest.json; displaying the [web app install banner](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/); etc.), and that my app is hosted at http://example.com.

An Android user navigates to that URL, sees the install banner, and installs the app to their home screen.

Then, they launch the app from the newly created icon on their home screen.

At that point: **what browser is the app running in?**

I've seen mention of something called [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html); is this the browser-like wrapper that serves as the runtime environment for my app?

Or something else?

(I'm essentially trying to confirm that my app, once installed to the home screen, will have access to all of the browser APIs that it needs. I may need to target Android 6 – so if the answer is different for that version than for Android 8, that would be very helpful information as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to clarify is that PWAs are not hybrid apps. They are running in standard browser environments with the options of hiding the browser chrome. A hybrid app is web technology that is packaged into a native app and deployed to the Play Store/App Store.

For the most part PWAs will open in whatever browser engine the user installed them with. The exception seems to be Firefox on Android Oreo when the PWA is installed via WebAPK. That seemed to run in Chrome even when launched from Firefox.

Ultimately you are building a website and you can not guarantee what browsers you users will have. Use proper feature detection to enable/disable features and when something critical isn't supported direct users to where they can get modern browsers.